# Adding a user authentication login page to Hot Towel SPA

Tags: javascript, durandal, hottowel

I'm developing a single page application using Hot Towel and I'd like to add a page that will handle user authentication.  I have a login page that opens inside the application that makes a call to an API that returns the user details required.

What I would like to do is to move this page to before the application start (before the splash page is shown).  At the moment, the application is triggering in VS2013 as soon as it is started.  How can I add a login page to the project that will delay the firing of the main.js until after the login process has completed?

Answer (score -1):

**Main.js** fires off at the bottom of your **index.cshtml**. So you can probably add code in to the `<script>` contained within the  section.

Comment: Please clarify the second sentence in your answer.  Also, refrain from conjecture.  If you do not have a specific, working solution for the OP, then offer your answer as a comment instead.